# JS autoclick button after 4 sec. (Greasemonkey)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Hello how to make a simple code in JS to Greasemonkey which click button on page after 4 sec? I'm fully beginner in JS.

Here is code of this button ;):

```
<a class="doIt" href="#" onClick="func_x()"></a>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    unsafeWindow.func_x(); // onclick event function
}, 4000);
```

or better yet

```
setTimeout(function() {
    location.assign("javascript:func_x()"); // onclick event function
}, 4000);
```

Comment: That code will not work as posted -- needs `unsafeWindow`.  I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                       false, false, false, false,
                       0, null);
    var link = document.querySelector("a.doIt");
    link.dispatchEvent(evt);
}, 4000);
```

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initMouseEvent
- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent

Live example:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/dispatchEvent.html